# Weird behavour of strtok in C?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I was writing a program in which I want to print common words between two strings . Well I use two loops and split those strings in those two loops . But didn't get the requisite result . Then I changed the program a bit and then I researched that outer loop run only once . Didn't able fathom why ? Anybody any idea ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "Japan Korea Spain Germany Australia France ";
    char str2[] = "England USA Russia Italy Australia India Nepal France";
    char *tar1 = strtok(str1," ");
    char *tar2 = NULL;
    while(tar1)
    {
       tar2 = strtok(str2," ");
       while(tar2)
       {
          if(strcmp(tar1,tar2)) printf("%s %s\n",tar1 , tar2);
          tar2 = strtok(NULL," ");
       }
       tar1 = strtok(NULL," ");
       tar2 = NULL;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(strcmp(tar1,tar2))`...sure? in case match is there, `if` will be FALSE...

Comment: You cannot use `strtok` on two different strings at the same time. I suggest `strtok_s` or `strtok_r` whichever is available. Even then, you can parse each string only once, not in the nested loop you hope for. You need to extract the token pointers into arrays first, then perform the nested loop search.

Comment: split to store to arrays then loop. because strtok family would change the string.

Comment: Hi Sourav , I mentioned I changed the program . I know I need to put a NOT(!) there . Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `strtok` on two different strings at the same time, and you cannot parse a string more than once, because `strtok` has already modified the string by breaking it with `nul` terminators.

This example extracts the token pointers into an array of pointers for each input string, before checking for matches.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTR 20
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "Japan Korea Spain Germany Australia France ";
    char str2[] = "England USA Russia Italy Australia India Nepal France";
    char *tar1[MAXSTR];
    char *tar2[MAXSTR];
    char *tok;
    int ind1 = 0, ind2 = 0;
    int i, j;

    tok = strtok(str1, " \t");
    while(tok != NULL && ind1 < MAXSTR) {
        tar1[ind1++] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

    tok = strtok(str2, " \t");
    while(tok != NULL && ind2 < MAXSTR) {
        tar2[ind2++] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

    for(i=0; i<ind1; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<ind2; j++) {
            if(strcmp(tar1[i], tar2[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", tar1[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Australia
France
```

Comment: Maybe mention `strtok_r`, this might help .

Comment: @phoxis I mentioned that in my comment at the top, under the question. However, you can only tokenise a string once, so might as well tokenise them before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

> The strtok() function **breaks** a string into a sequence of zero or more
>   nonempty tokens.

In other words: `' '` is replaced with a NUL (0) by `strtok`.

In consequence, you can not use `tar2 = strtok(str2," ");` twice with the same string.

And as pointed out by @WeatherVane: You cannot use `strtok` on two different strings at the same time.

An alternative to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "Japan Korea Spain Germany Australia France ";
    char str2[] = "England USA Russia Italy Australia India Nepal France";
    char *tar = strtok(str1, " ");
    char *ptr;
    size_t sz;

    while (tar) {
        if ((ptr = strstr(str2, tar)) != NULL) {
            /* First string or starts with " " */
            if ((ptr == str2) || (*(ptr -1) == ' ')) {
                sz = strlen(tar);
                /* Last string or ends with " " */
                if ((*(ptr + sz) == ' ') || (*(ptr + sz) == '\0')) {
                    puts(tar);
                }
            }
        }
        tar = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Australia
France
```